# Optimizing a Q3DBars graph

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt3d, qtcharts

I am developing a Qt application that requires visualizations of very large data sets.  I was hoping to use Qt's 3D graphing functionality (Q3DBars) to make the data more easily understood.  However, I am having difficulty getting a reasonable framerate.  [image: Overview]

[image]

I have done the below in hopes that the framerate would improve.  No effect.

```
bars.setReflection(false);
bars.setReflectivity(false);    
bars.setOptimizationHints(...::QAbstract3DGraph::OptimizationHint::OptimizationStatic);
bars.setShadowQuality(QAbstract3DGraph::ShadowQuality::ShadowQualityNone);
bars.setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface);
```

I have a GTX1080 and windows records 40% GPU usage as I rotate the graph.  However, the CPU is loaded significantly during the same rotation.

What can be done to further offload work to the GPU and/or optimize the rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the other 3D graph classes, I have discovered that Q3DSurface runs smoothly with the same data set.  I am unsure what the specific difference is but I suspect the surface is rendered in a vastly different way.  Initially, the image looked unclear.  [image]

However, after disabling the wireframe the image became very clear.